# TD wight everywhere

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Please help, I want **td** was the same size everywhere. And that was a vertical scrolling.
I used height and this doesn't help.

I'm styled only **th**(his wight)

http://imageshack.us/f/402/feedbacktz.jpg/

```
  <table class="table table-striped" id="feedback_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 25px">Anything</th>
        <th style="width: 70px">Anything</th>
        <th style="width: 80px">Anything</th>
        <th style="white-space:nowrap; width: 125px">Anything</th>
        <th style="width: 360px">Anything</th>
        <th style="width: 114px">Anything</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

if the reviews contain lots of text, the Text review is too broad (see attachment). Scrolling is required to see the edit button.

Comment: What have you did.Please give your code? And make the question more understandable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the table with.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="feedback_table" width="774">
```

or

```
table.table { width: 774px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help in your case.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

i have modified the code according to your need for example below

```
<p>overflow:scroll</p><table>
<tr>
  <td>
  <div class="scroll">You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.</div>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

//CSS

```
div.scroll { 
background-color:#00FFFF; 
width:100px; height:100px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: sorry, w3schools is a bad source too